# How do I install over an encrypted disk?

Tags: system-installation, encryption

I got a new (old) laptop, and was excited to try something new. So I gave Zorin OS a shot. However the initial charm wore off and I decided to move to Ubuntu (or maybe Mint?). But when I installed Zorin I encrypted the full drive. So do I need to make any special considerations, or can I just do a clean install and call it good? I've seen some recommendations for decrypting the disk first, but (1) it sounds like a lot of work, and (2) I have nothing sensitive on the fresh install of Zorin to lose. If it's better to decrypt the drive then I'll do it. But I'd rather cut my losses and move on.

Also as a side note, do I need any special considerations installing over a previous distro? Again, I don't want to save any folders or files. Just do a clean install.

EDIT: Solved. I just did a clean install and it went swimmingly. Now on Ubuntu 14.04 without a hitch!

Comment: Ubuntu is able to overwrite the partition(s) with the necessary files to provide a running system, no matter what has been on the partitions before. Depending on which paritions Zorin used, the Ubuntu installation routine looks different, please edit and add your partition setup

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is able to overwrite the partition(s) with the necessary files to provide a running system, no matter what has been on the partitions before.